# Sewage pump turning on without any sinks or toilet installed

Tags: plumbing

In my home I have a sump pump and a pump referenced as a ‘sludge pump’. Even though there  are no bathrooms or sinks in the basement, the sludge pump kicks on occasionally. Why is this happening? And why do the pipes ‘hammer’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some systems are controlled by plc's programmable logic controllers that automatically pump every zone to make sure that a level sensor failure won't have your lower level floating in poop. I omit cyclic pumping or have with triple redundant sensors, I have seen 2 die but never all 3, it just may be the safety to prevent a very smelly situation. If it is a diagram sludge pump one than can pump almost solids ever firing if the pump makes some noise, you may not need this level of protection but if you do and it is not working things can go bad fast.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Only the electrical line is coming is from the pump, so I’m fairly certain there isn’t a PLC controller. The house was built in 1991, with the unfinished basement plumbing drains and vents ‘roughed in’. This is out of my expertise, so I’m still confused why the pump runs when the only thing draining into the pit is the AC condensation drain line. Hmm..